# Execute ForEach in Parallel - C#

Tags: c#, optimization, foreach, datatable, task

I have a `foreach` statement like

```
// distinctValues is DataTable with thousand of rows
foreach (DataRow row in distinctValues.Rows)
{
    // Lots of Statements
}
```

Is there a way to execute `forfach` *Statement* in *Parallel* for faster execution?

Comment: Googling the text in your question title gives a whole bunch of relevant, useful resources, including the Microsoft documentation for [Parallel.ForeEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.8) right at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the only (little) difficulty is that `DataTable` (if I guessed `distinctValues` type right) *doesn't implement* `IEnumerable<DataRow>` interface
However, you can easily obtain it with a help of `.AsEnumerable()` *extension method*:

`Parallel.ForEach`  implemenation

```
  Parallel.ForEach(distinctValues.AsEnumerable(), row => { 
    // Lots of Statements 
  });
```

*PLinq* (Parallel Linq) code which can be more convenient for experimenting:

```
  distinctValues
    .AsEnumerable()
    .AsParallel()
    //.AsOrdered()
    //.WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)
    //.WithDegreeOfParallelism(4)
    .ForAll(row => {
       // Lots of Statements
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use,

```
Parallel.ForEach(list,(item)=>{
//do works
})
```

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop)